# Click event not detected after Auth0 authentication in React App

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs, auth0

I have some jQuery code in my React App.js that controls my nav bar at a certain media query. @media(max-width: 870px) the nav bar is supposed to slide down and reveal its nav items on click on the nav ul element. Everything works fine until the user authenticates with Auth0 and is redirected back to the same webpage. At that time the nav bar stops detecting clicks and does NOT slide down making it impossible to even log out as the log out button is within the nav. Refreshing the page does not help.

Here is my App.js:

```
import React from "react";
import './App.css';
import Navibar from "./components/Navibar";
import CarouselFront from "./components/CarouselFront";
import comp1 from "./components/Comp1";
import comp2 from "./components/Comp2";
import Footer from "./components/Footer";
import $ from "jquery";
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Switch, Route } from "react-router-dom";
import Spinner from 'react-bootstrap/Spinner';
import { useAuth0 } from "@auth0/auth0-react";
import ProtectedRoute from "./auth/protected-route";

$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".menu-icon").on("click", function () {
        $("nav ul").toggleClass("showing");
    });
});

// Scrolling Effect

$(window).on("scroll", function () {
    if ($(window).scrollTop()) {
        $("nav").addClass("black");
    }

    else {
        $("nav").removeClass("black");
    }
});

function App() {

    const { isLoading } = useAuth0();

    if (isLoading) {
        return <Spinner animation="border" role="status" style={{ top: "50%", left: "50%", transform: "translate(-50 %, -50 %)", position: "absolute" }} />;
    }

    return (

        <Router>
            <Navibar />
            <Switch>
                <ProtectedRoute path="/comp1" component={comp1} />
                <ProtectedRoute path="/comp2" component={comp2} />
                <Route exact path="/">
                    <CarouselFront />
                </Route>
            </Switch>
            <Footer />
        </Router >
    )
};

export default App;
```

And here is the Auth0ProviderWithHistory component:

```
import React from "react";
import { useHistory } from "react-router-dom";
import { Auth0Provider } from "@auth0/auth0-react";

const Auth0ProviderWithHistory = ({ children }) => {
    const domain = process.env.REACT_APP_AUTH0_DOMAIN;
    const clientId = process.env.REACT_APP_AUTH0_CLIENT_ID;

    const history = useHistory();

    const onRedirectCallback = (appState) => {
        history.push(appState?.returnTo || window.location.pathname);
    };

    return (
        <Auth0Provider
            domain={domain}
            clientId={clientId}
            redirectUri={window.location.origin}
            onRedirectCallback={onRedirectCallback}
        >
            {children}
        </Auth0Provider>
    );
};

export default Auth0ProviderWithHistory;
```

Is there something I need to change to make this code work as expected? Thanks.

Comment: Are you using JQuery for some reason?

Comment: I used a jQuery-based template for the nav bar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try move this logic inside `useEffect` block

```
useEffect(() => {
  $(".menu-icon").on("click", function () {
        $("nav ul").toggleClass("showing");
  });

  $(window).on("scroll", function () {
    if ($(window).scrollTop()) {
        $("nav").addClass("black");
    }
    else {
        $("nav").removeClass("black");
    }
  });
}, []);
```

Comment: It didn't help ((

Comment: Try to add window.location.pathname to useEffect dependencies

Comment: Didn't work either. Here is the code:     useEffect(() => {
        $(".menu-icon").on("click", function () {
            $("nav ul").toggleClass("showing");
        });
    }, [window.location.pathname]);

Comment: Now I moved the useEffect code block to the Navibar component and it worked like magic even without the window.location.pathname dependency. Thanks!